# Can I partial integrate contravariant derivatives?

Tags: general-relativity, integration

Let us assume I have the integral

$$\int_{\mathcal{M}}\text{d}r\ r^2\phi(r)\partial_r^2\phi(r).$$

If I partial integrate I get

$$\int_{\mathcal{M}}\text{d}r\ r^2\phi(r)\partial_r^2\phi(r)=r^2\phi(r)\partial_r \phi(r)\Big|_{\partial\mathcal{M}}-\int_{\mathcal{M}}\text{d}r \ \partial_r[r^2\phi(r)]\partial_r\phi(r).$$

However, in this particular case, we know that the metric component $g^{rr}=r^2$ so that $r^2\partial_r=\partial^r$. If I partial integrate the contravariant derivative, I find what I think is a mismatch

$$\int_{\mathcal{M}}\text{d}r\ \phi(r)\partial^r\partial_r\phi(r)=r^2\phi(r)\partial_r \phi(r)\Big|_{\partial\mathcal{M}}-\int_{\mathcal{M}}\text{d}r\ \partial^r\phi(r)\partial_r\phi(r),$$

but the last piece $\int_{\mathcal{M}}\text{d}r\ r^2\partial_r\phi(r)\partial_r\phi(r)$ does not yield the same term as in the covariant case. Is there something wrong in the computation? Can we partial integrate with contravariant derivatives?

Answer (score 0):

Integration by parts is nothing else than a simple consequence of the product rule $\partial_r[\phi(r)\psi(r)]=\partial_r\phi(r)\,\psi(r)+\phi(r)\,\partial_r\psi(r)\,.$ Obviously, it is also true that $$r^2\partial_r[\phi(r)\psi(r)]=r^2\partial_r\phi(r)\,\psi(r)+\phi(r)\,r^2\partial_r\psi(r)\,$$ holds. You may write this as a product rule for $\partial^r$:
$$
\partial^r[\phi(r)\psi(r)]=\partial^r\phi(r)\,\psi(r)+\phi(r)\,\partial^r\psi(r)\,.
$$
**However**: the other ingredients for integration by parts is the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$
\int_a^b\partial_r[\phi(r)\psi(r)]\,dr=\phi(b)\psi(b)-\phi(a)\psi(a)
$$
which holds for $\partial_r$ but not for $\partial^r=r^2\partial_r\,.$